# How to Print TensorFlow Network Structure？

Tags: tensorflow

I defined a tensorflow network structure, and then I wanted to print it just like pytorch.
Does tensorflow have a corresponding function?
Or how should I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize your Tensorflow network using Tensorboard.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard[Tensorboard details](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard)

Above link given complete details of how to do it.

Comment: I know it,but I just want to save a simple txt file so that I can view the network structure and parameters, I think tensorboard is not very convenient.

Comment: I suppose for that you may have to write your own code - read summary log file using iterator and write in the text file, except if there is any specific Github project in which its already implemented.